# Why is the result different when storing the result of filter() function in a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using the `filter()` and `splice()` functions to edit and set values in an array. However, I've noticed that what I'm returning is different from what is being stored in the variable.

For example: I console log `myArray` and I return myArray, both of these return `[1,5,30,1]`; However, when I `console.log(myArr2)` the result is `[1,5,29,1]`.

I know that if I return `(e)` instead, I will get the correct array, but I'm confused as to why returning `myArray` wouldn't work as well?

```js
const myArray = [1, 5, 29, 30, 1];

const myArr2 = myArray.filter(function(e, i)
{
    if (e === 29)
    {
        console.log(e, i);
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
    }

    console.log(myArray);
    return myArray;
});
    
console.log(myArr2);
```

Comment: Why `splice` while iterating? That doesn't make sense, just return a truthy value if you want to include the item in the resulting array.

Comment: oh wow. I didn't know that you could just do that. sorry! I am still a beginner and learning. Thanks so much!

Comment: `splice` is modifying `myArray` while you're iterating it with `filter`. No wonder that you'll see unwanted side-effects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will mutate `myArray` while you are iterating on the filtering procedure and that will have **side-effects**.

## Explanation:

On the filtering procedure, when you are deciding to filter or not `e` when it is `29`, the index `i` will be `2`. At that time, `29` is removed from `myArray` and `30` will be now at index `2`. This is cause by the code:

```
if (e ===29)
{
    console.log(e, i);
    myArray.splice(i, 1);
}
```

However, at the same time you return a **truthy** value (`return myArray`) for `e = 29` saying that element `29` will be in the filtered array (`myArr2`). Now at the next iteration, at index `i = 3`, the value for `e` will be `1` since you already mutated `myArray` removing element `30`, and then `30` will be never visited on the filtered procedure.

## Solution:

If you need to get a new array with element `29` filtered out, then you can simple return `false` for it on the filtering procedure:

```js
const myArray = [1, 5, 29, 30, 1];

const myArr2 = myArray.filter(function(e)
{
    if (e === 29)
        return false;

    return true;
});

console.log("myArray:", myArray); // Not mutated!
console.log("myArr2:", myArr2); // 29 is out!
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, in a simplified way:

```js
const myArray = [1, 5, 29, 30, 1];
console.log("filtered array:", myArray.filter(e => e !== 29));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove specific value from the array using filter in javascript. You can try this way. may be it fulfill your demand.

```js
const myArray = [1,5,29,30,1];
const result = myArray.filter(item => item != 29);
console.log(result);
```